# How to make exeption for file descriptor redirection -- (3>&1) for the whole script except for some functions which need to be displayed in tty

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Basically I have a function for collecting logs

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3 15 9
exec 1>/tmp/log.out 2>&1
```

It work fine but whenever there was a select function like **"select opt in "${arr[@]}"**"

the options did not displayed properly on the terminal, all the options got redirected log.out

```
select opt in "${net_arr[@]}"
do 
    if [ "$REPLY" -eq "$net_rec" ];
    then
      echo "Exiting..."
      break;
    elif [ 1 -le "$REPLY" ] && [ "$REPLY" -le $((net_rec-1)) ];
    then
      sub_menu ${net_arr[$((REPLY+1))]}
      break;
    else
      echo "Incorrect Input: Select a number 1-$net_rec"
    fi
done
```

**options can only be found in log.out**

```
Select I/F: 
1) ens33
2) ens37
3) lo
4) virbr0
```

I tried to wrap the function in another function like the below but after fd 1 got redirected to fd 3 (exec 2>&4 1>&3) everything is displayed on the terminal instead of going to log.out like it suppose to. Command
**exec 3>&1 4>&2** doesnt seem to revert it

```
input_cheat() {
    exec 2>&4 1>&3
    $*
    echo "wait........"
    exec 3>&1 4>&2
}
```

Comment: Is this XY question? What is that you really want to do? You want to redirect messages from your script to a file, except for a trap? `fd 3 ( log.out)` ? It's `3>&1`, and options are getting displayed at `1>/tmp/log.out`. How is it fd3?

Comment: I want to redirect all message to a file except for a function
Yes it was suppose to be "all options got redirected to log.out" and not fd3 since fd3 is now the terminal : )))) thanks